# Double NAT with access to both gateway web interfaces

Tags: networking, router, nat, subnet

I have a Cisco Linksys E3000 home router that I appreciate. However, my new (but temporary) ISP will want me to use their Huawei router for their service once I get connected next week.

This creates a double NAT, which I assume is going to work. However, both routers work in the 192.168.1.x space (class a) by default and both web interfaces and standard gateways will sit at 192.168.1.1.

Is this going to cause headaches? And whats the best way to solve them if it does?

I would love to be able to access the web interface of my ISP router from within the local network created by my Cisco router.

Answer (score 1):

Just renumber one or the other router to 192.168.2.x instead. Then there will be no problem. From the inner network, you should be able to reach the outer router.

Why not just use both in the same network though? What do you get in exchange for living with double NAT?

Comment: I am not able to predict the implications of that. Won't they conflict when they both occupy 192.168.1.1 ? How about two DHCP servers both handing out IP addresses?

Comment: @NielsB. "*Won't they conflict when they both occupy 192.168.1.1 ?*" Sure, so don't give them both 192.168.1.1, make one of them 192.168.1.2. "*How about two DHCP servers both handing out IP addresses?*" So you disable the DHCP server in the one that doesn't connect to the Internet. Are you accepting double NAT just because you don't understand how to have two routers in the same network?

Comment: I never had to deal with two routers on the same network before, so I am uncertain about the feasibility. Anyway, you seem quite certain that it's manageable, so I'll give it a shot.